# Правила безопасности Firebase DataBase

Tags: java, android, firebase-database

Я пишу приложение под Андроид на Java, оно имеет регистрацию. База данных называется accounts, внутри нее создаются новые записи на основе айди пользователя(с помощью кода получаю количество записей, и эту цифру использую как айди записи в accounts). Получается такое - accounts > 0,1,2,3,4 и так далее

Как мне настроить базу данных так, чтобы пользователь мог смотреть только свою запись?

Comment: Про правила безопасности не скажу, но вот автогенерация ID у вас сделана, скорее всего, неправильно. Вроде как в Firebase нельзя узнать кол-во записей, не скачав все записи. Что полностью сломает ваше приложение, когда записей станет много. Также тут не будет гарантии непересечения ID при одновременной записи. Используйте лучше встроенный механизм генерации ID. А ещё лучше - не используйте Firebase - от него проблем больше чем пользы, если, конечно, вы не используете его для учебных или тестовых целей.

Comment: Согласен, очень много сложностей... Но приложение маленькое, не использует большую базу данных. Но я понял, спасибо

Comment: А не подскажете, как реализовать получение этого ключа в коде Java, и что за правила нужны, чтобы при регистрации юзер мог читать и писать только в свою НОВУЮ запись в БД?

Comment: Вот так записывайте данные https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push - вам вернётся, вроде, объект с записанными данными, где и будет ID. Ну или используйте уже имеющийся у вас ID юзера в качестве ID для БД. Про правила не скажу - пару лет назад пытался в них вникнуть, но мне стало скучно и я бросил попытки разобраться)